# Reassign ArrayList in a better Way

Tags: scala, collections, scala-collections, scalastyle

The below code is working, but its looking odd to me, is there any better way to this.

```
var res:scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap[String,scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]]=??
var arList = new ArrayList[String]()
res.keySet.map(arList.add(_))
//here res key set changed so i want to reassign the list by new keySet
res=??                                                        //updated
arList.clear
res.keySet.map(arList.add(_))
```

its looking very odd that to call the `.clear` on `arList`

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your actual requirement?

Comment: Why not using the `res.keySet`? Why do you need a `List` for that?

Comment: @NaderHadjiGhanbari becuase `res.keSet` is `scala.collection.Set[String]` and i need  `java.util.ArrayList[String]` , i Have to pass it for another method that needs `Array List`

Comment: Just use `toLoist` method then: `res.keySet.toList`

Comment: @NaderHadjiGhanbari it will convert into `List` not `ArrayList`

Comment: Then refer to the answer by @Eugene :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use default JavaConverters.

```
  import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
  val list = new java.util.ArrayList(res.keySet.asJavaCollection)
```

I didn't get why do you need to do clear, is it some requirement that you pass ArrayList once and update it's content later?